# How would I structure multiple products that are mapped multiple services in azure service fabric?

Tags: service, deployment, azure-service-fabric

If I want to offer x number of products (to consumers) and there are y number of services that support these x number of products, how would I structure this in the service fabric? The typical examples I see for service fabric deployment are one application type maps to multiple service types. In my scenario, application type A1 depends on service types S1 and S2 and application type A2 depends on service type S2 and S3. As you can see, there is a common service S2 and I would like to have only one instance of S2 for both apps (instead of one instance for A1 and another for A2). (Let me worry about how S2 is to be authored when used for A1 vs A2).

Any help is appreciated.

Raghu/..

Comment: Is it an option to host S2 separately in A3 and use it from both A1S1 and A2S3?

Comment: In a world of micro-services, does this mean there has to be one application for every micro-service?

Comment: Any body? Is this how it should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that each micro-service should be an app in the context of service fabric.